# Picture box moves with timer, but it lags behind?

Tags: c#

I'm not sure how to explain this. I have the code set up so when the timer ticks, it checks to see if the picture box is at a certain location. If it isn't, then it should move a little bit closer. It works in moving, but each time it moves, it generates a white field behind it, and it grows. I have the tick set to 750, so each time it ticks, the picture moves farther than it should, and each time it goes farther than the previous time. Here's the code.

```
        private void ZombieTimer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ZombieTimer1.Tick += new System.EventHandler(ZombieTimer1_Tick);
        enemyNPC1.Show();
        ZombieTimer1.Start();
        if (enemyNPC1.Location.X < 280)
        {
            enemyNPC1.Left = enemyNPC1.Left + 1;
            ZombieTimer1.Stop();
            ZombieTimer1.Start();
        }                        
    }
```

Comment: You're adding a new tick handler every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the declaration of the event handler to the constructor for your window.

At the moment you get another event handler every time the event fires, which causes the event to fire twice the second time, and four times the next time, etc.